# tricky memoization

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, memoization

Let's say I have the NDSolve example for documentation involving splitting 2nd order into set of 1st order ODEs:

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0}, {x, 
y}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

I need to solve my second order system like this for various reasons.

My ODE is more complicated, and depends on some other parameters call them $(a,b)$, and so when I solved it as a second order system I used memoization in the form below, so that if a solution for a given parameter set had already been computed, Mathematica wouldn't redo it all again. I would like to do this, or something like it for the first order system and where NDSolve is giving the two variables $x[a,b],y[a,b]$.

```
x[a_,b_]:=
 x[a,b] = x /.NDSolve[{eq[a,b],x[0]== init[a,b],x'[0]==dinit[a,b],x,{r, 0, 10}][[1]];
```

Comment: Have you, by any chance, seen the [`NDSolve\`StateData` tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I see this right, you have one single function call (`NDSolve`) depending on two parameters which results in a vector (the interp. functions). Here is an equivalent minimal example function for this call

```
f[a_, b_] := {b, a}
```

The underlying issue is now, that you always get both answers from `f` (`x` and `y`) even if you need only `x` for a specific choice of `a` and `b`. You can solve this by memorizing both, `x` and `y`, no matter which function you call.

```
x[a_, b_] := {x[a, b], y[a, b]} = f[a, b];
y[a_, b_] := {x[a, b], y[a, b]} = f[a, b];
```

A quit check shows you that you memorize the values for `x` and `y` even if you compute only `x`

```
Table[x[a, b], {a, 0, 2}, {b, 0, 2}];
?x
?y
```

Lets try this with your `NDSolve` example. I only wrapped `Module` around to localize `x` and `y`.

```
ClearAll[x, y, f];
f[a_, b_] := Module[{x, y}, {x, y} /. 
   First@NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == a, y[0] == b}, 
    {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}]];

x[a_, b_] := {x[a, b], y[a, b]} = f[a, b];
y[a_, b_] := {x[a, b], y[a, b]} = f[a, b];

Table[x[a, b], {a, 0, 2}, {b, 0, 2}];

?y
```

Finally, the repetition of the exact same function definition for `x` and `y` looks kind of like we are not experts. Lets improve this. The only thing which is different is the head of the left side in the `:=`. So we write the line one time and substitute `x` and `y` resp.

```
SetDelayed[#[a_, b_], {x[a, b], y[a, b]} = f[a, b]] & /@ {x, y}
```

Comment: one small problem with this is on the initial call, if I do say:  x[1,2][3.0] instead of getting a numeric answer back I get two interpolating functions. The second call works fine, and gives the result desired. This is in contrast to standard memoization. I think it can be solved by just changing to x[a_, b_] := ({x[a, b], y[a, b]} = f[a, b]; x[a,b]) etc

Comment: @fpghost Yes, I haven't addressed that. I only worked out the problem with the memoization. I'll have a look at it later.