# Making use of side effects to speed up NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, matrix

I am solving

```
NDSolveValue[eqs, {A, B}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

a system of matrix differential equations

```
eqs={
 D[A[t],t] == rhsA[A[t], B[t], Z[A[t], B[t]]],
 D[B[t],t] == rhsB[A[t], B[t], Z[A[t], B[t]]],
 A[0] == Az,
 B[0] == Bz
}
```

where `rhsA` and `rhsB` are numerically cheap functions, e.g.,

```
rhsA[a_?ArrayQ, b_?ArrayQ, z_?ArrayQ]:= 0.03 * a.a + First[z] * a; 
rhsB[a_?ArrayQ, b_?ArrayQ, z_?ArrayQ]:= 0.03 * b.b + First[z] * b;
```

And for simplicity, we initialize as follows

```
Az = RandomReal[{0.,1.},{20,20}]; 
Bz = RandomReal[{0.,1.},{30,30}];
```

The auxiliary function `Z` is super expensive, e.g.,

```
Z[a_?ArrayQ, b_?ArrayQ]:= Module[{}, Pause[0.1]; {0.1}]
```

The details are, however, not important as I am asking about the code organization not optimization.

I would like to know how to organize the code so that `Z` is evaluated the *same* number of times as `rhsA` or `rhsB`. This seems to be a very natural requirement. If solving manually, I would first evaluate `Z` every time step and then pass it as a parameter to the two functions. Or I would call `rhsA`, which would involve a call to `Z`, memorize the value of latter function and re-use it in `rhsB`. But I cannot figure our the syntax to achieve it in MA. One part of the problem is that MA recognizes a matrix ODE only when the `ArrayQ` test is passed. Trying to combine two arrays of different dimensions into one rugged array destroys this property.

### Comment

There is, of course, a way to achieve what I want by flattening all arrays and combining then into one list. By I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: For a start, you could use "MatrixPower instead of repeated matrix multiplication.

Comment: How are you counting the number of times that `Z `is evaluated?

Comment: I should have been more precise.  Perhaps you should use `EventMonitor` to be sure.

Comment: On its face, it seems to me that memoization of the value of the expensive function `Z` could reduce the number of times it is evaluated in a single iteration, E.g. [(11281)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11281/27951).

Comment: @MarcoB Right, however, to store the function's values for the entire time-interval is an overshoot.

Comment: Hm. One could try to memoize in a queue of finite length or in some sort of rotating buffer... Whenever more than, say 2 elements are in the buffer, the oldest one is popped upon insertion of a new one...

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand a bit on the rotating buffer: This can be implemented easily with `Association`:

```
Z[x_] := Module[{}, Pause[0.01]; VeryVeryComplicatedFunction[x]];
maxsize = 3;
Zbuffer = Association[];
Zbuffered[x_] := Module[{result}, result = Zbuffer[x];
   If[MissingQ[result], 
    If[Length[Zbuffer] >= maxsize, 
     KeyDropFrom[Zbuffer, First@Keys[Zbuffer]]];
    result = Z[x];
    AssociateTo[Zbuffer, x -> result];];
   result];
```

Now we apply `Z` and `Zbuffered` to a random list in which each element is repeated 10 times:

```
queries = Flatten[Transpose[ConstantArray[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 24], 10]]];
a = Z /@ queries; // AbsoluteTiming // First
b = Zbuffered /@ queries; // AbsoluteTiming  // First
a == b
Zbuffer
```

> 2.6427
>
> 0.265437
>
> True
>
> <|
> 0.922188 -> VeryVeryComplicatedFunction[ 0.922188],
>
> -0.289718 -> VeryVeryComplicatedFunction[-0.289718],
>
> 0.168509 -> VeryVeryComplicatedFunction[ 0.168509] |>

For this one has to know that `AssociateTo` always appends new keys to the back. Hence we may simply drop the first key. Alternatively, one could also employ downvalues, but erasing the oldest key may not be as simple as they get reordered.

Of course, this approach adds its own overhead. So `Z` would better be *really* expensive.

Comment: I should probably say that one can judge the performance of the method by comparing it with the "pack/unpack all arrays into a vector" approach. For my problem in hand the latter is simpler and faster.  Anyway, thanks for an interesting idea.